# Stochastic representation of Laplace equation with Neumann boundary condition

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider nice domain $D\subset \mathbb R^d$ and  $\Delta u =0$ with $u\big|_{\partial D}=g$. It is well known that $u(x)=E^x[g(B(\tau))]$ where $\tau$ is exit time of $B$ from the domain $D$.

What if we consider Neumann boundary conditions? Is there a stochastic representation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, see Section 4.4.2 in "Stochastic Differential Equations, Backward SDEs, Partial Differential Equations" by Pardoux and Rascanu.